# Different hashes during CRAM-MD5 authentication

Tags: go, hash

As an exercise, I'm trying to implement a mock SMTP server with CRAM-MD5 authentication in Go (without following RFC 2195, since it looks like it doesn't matter to the client what format the pre-hashed challenge is in; I also assume there is only one user "bob" with password "pass"). But I can't seem to get it right as the hash in response is always different from what I have on the server. I send the email using Go as such (running it as a separate package):

```
{...}
smtp.SendMail("localhost:25", smtp.CRAMMD5Auth("bob", "pass"),
   "bob@localhost", []string{"alice@localhost"}, []byte("Hey Alice!\n"))
{...}
```

Here's what I do when I get the authentication acknowledgement from the client:

```
{...}
case strings.Contains(ms, "AUTH CRAM-MD5"):
    rndbts = make([]byte, 16) // Declared at package level
    b64b := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(16))
    rand.Read(rndbts)
    base64.StdEncoding.Encode(b64b, rndbts)
    _, err = conn.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("334 %x\n", b64b)))
{...}
```

And this is what I do with the client's response:

```
{...}
 {
    ms = strings.TrimRight(ms, "\r\n") // The response to the challenge
    ds, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(ms)
    s := strings.Split(string(ds), " ")
    login := s[0] // I can get the login from the response.
    h := hmac.New(md5.New, []byte("pass"))
    h.Write(rndbts)
    c := make([]byte, 0, ourHash.Size()) // From smtp/auth.go, not sure why we need this.
    validPass := hmac.Equal(h.Sum(c), []byte(s[1]))
    {...}   
}
{...}
```

And the `validPass` is never `true`. I omitted error handling from the excerpts for brevity, but they're there in the actual code (though they're always `nil`). Why are the hashes different? I have looked at the source code for net/smtp, and it seems to me that I'm going in the right direction, but not quite.

Comment: `rndbts = make([]byte, 16) // Declared at package level` -- this looks like a death wish. You should have this variable be scoped as locally as possible. Sharing random bits across users like this will invalidate your security.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I get it, but right now there is only one user as it's a mock, not something I plan on using for any actual purpose.

Comment: The conversion to string and then back to bytes seems problematic to me.

Comment: From the Wikipedia page, it looks like there's a conversion to hex completely missing from your code?

Comment: In general, I'm having a hard time mapping your code to what's described on Wikipedia. You should be building up a string and then comparing it to what the client sent, but instead it looks like you're comparing against only part of the decoded response from the client? Maybe you can explain the algorithm you're following in English first and then comment the code to show how it implements that algorithm.

Comment: My understanding: 1) HMAC the challenge (with the password), 2) convert that hash to lowercase hex, 3) prepend username + " ", 4) base64 encode the whole thing, 5) compare that with what the client sent you. Your code doesn't seem to follow that algorithm.

Comment: Also, `fmt.Sprintf("334 %x\n", b64b)` looks wrong to me. Shouldn't you be using `%s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps! Runnable version is at https://play.golang.org/p/-8shx_IcLV. Also note that you'll need to fix your `%x` (should be `%s`) so you're sending the right challenge down to the client. Right now I think you're trying to hex-encode your base64 string.

Once you've fixed that, I believe this code should help you to construct the right response string on the server and compare it to what the client sent.

```
// Example values taken from http://susam.in/blog/auth-cram-md5/

challenge := []byte("<17893.1320679123@tesseract.susam.in>")
username := []byte("alice")
password := []byte("wonderland")
clientResponse := []byte("YWxpY2UgNjRiMmE0M2MxZjZlZDY4MDZhOTgwOTE0ZTIzZTc1ZjA=")

// hash the challenge with the user's password
h := hmac.New(md5.New, password)
h.Write(challenge)
hash := h.Sum(nil)

// encode the result in lowercase hexadecimal
hexEncoded := hex.EncodeToString(hash)

// prepend the username and a space
toEncode := []byte(string(username) + " " + hexEncoded)

// base64-encode the whole thing
b64Result := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(toEncode)))
base64.StdEncoding.Encode(b64Result, toEncode)

// check that this is equal to what the client sent
if hmac.Equal(b64Result, clientResponse) {
    fmt.Println("Matches!")
}
```

Comment: The `%x` was indeed the culprit. I thought I had tried `%s` there, but looks like I had not. There was no error with the client's base64 decoding of the hex string from the server because a hex string can pass as valid base64 encoded string. Also I forgot to decode from hex string to byte slice when comparing hashes. Trying to cast a hex string to bytes like that is the wrong way to do it in that situation and using `hex` package is the right way. Thanks a lot!